# how to refer to a Drawable object by an id of type in

Tags: android, background, drawable

[From this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29):

```
public void setBackgroundResource (int resid)
```

Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.

So how do I refer to a Drawable object by an int id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common use case is

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mydrawable)
```

The R class contains an auto-generated int reference to each drawable resource in the project folder.

This has no use if you generate your `Drawable` in code or from any other source than the projects resources (that's why it's called setBackgroundRESOURCE()).

Comment: okay, this was pretty much the answer I expected. wonder why they tell you it can also be a Drawable object if there's no way to refer to it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Each id in `R.drawable` referers to one drawable object in the resource folder. Every drawable has one unique id. So you can reference a specific one by mentioning a specific id. As stated that's only valid for references to the apps resources. If you want to refer to any other drawable with an int, thats not possible with this function. Use `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)` instead.

Comment: okay, now I understand. the misunderstanding resulted from them using the word 'object' to describe an xml/bitmap file. I read it as being  `Drawable d = new Drawable()` type of object.